# Convert an object attribute to mapstruct

Tags: spring-boot, mapstruct

My DTO:

```
public class ObjectDTO implements Serializable {

private Long id;

private String title;

private Long parentId;
...
}
```

My Entity:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  @ManyToOne
  private MyObject parent;
....
}
```

My Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ObjectMapper extends EntityMapper<ObjectDTO, MyObject> {
  @Mapping(target = "parentId", source = "m.parent.id")
  ObjectDTO toDto(MyObject m);
}
```

Exception:

```
 error: Can't map property "Long parentId" to "MyObject parentId". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "MyObject map(Long value)". Occured at 'E toEntity(D dto)' in 'EntityMapper'.
```

Please tell me what is the reason, and what are the correct actions when extracting the attribute

UPDATE:
This is my interface for Mapper

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {
E toEntity(D dto);
D toDto(E entity);
}
```

Comment: But the current problem is in `toEntity` (not in `toDto`;)

Comment: I don't have an override for toEntity

Answer (score 0):

just do what mapstruct is telling you to do: you are missing a method with signature `MyObject map(Long value)` needed by autogenerated `toEntity()` method for property mapping `ObjectDTO.parentId` mapped to `MyObject.parent`.
Check MapStruct [`Object factories`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories); them may be the right way to solve your problem.